# Out of Memory at line XXXX

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, out-of-memory

can anyone help me how to resolve the out of memory error on my asp page? im using linq to sql.. after adding data several data.. like more than 10 rows. in the grid. an out of memory error occurs.. attached herewith is my add function..

```
public ServiceDetail checkservicedetailid()
{
    string ServiceName = ViewState["Tab"].ToString();
    ServiceDetail checkservicedetailid = ServiceDetails_worker.get(a => a.ServiceName == ServiceName && a.MarginAnalysisID == checkmarginanalysisid().MarginAnalysisID).SingleOrDefault();
    return checkservicedetailid;
}

public IEnumerable<ServiceDetail> get(Expression<Func<ServiceDetail, Boolean>> express)    
{ 
    return ServiceDetailsDB.ServiceDetails.Where(express); 
}

protected void btnSaveEmptyOC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
       if (checkservicedetailid() != null)
       {
           CashExpense tblCashExpenses = new CashExpense();
           Guid CashExpensesID = Guid.NewGuid();

           tblCashExpenses.CashExpensesID = CashExpensesID;
           tblCashExpenses.ServiceDetailsID = checkservicedetailid().ServiceDetailsID;
           tblCashExpenses.Description = txtDescriptionEmptyOC.Text;
           tblCashExpenses.Quantity = Decimal.Parse(txtQTYEmptyOC.Text);
           tblCashExpenses.UnitCost = Decimal.Parse(txtUnitCostEmptyOC.Text);
           tblCashExpenses.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
           tblCashExpenses.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
           tblCashExpenses.CashExpensesTypeID = "OTHER";

           CashExpenses_worker.insert(tblCashExpenses);
           CashExpenses_worker.submit();
           //Clear items after saving
           txtDescriptionEmptyOC.Text = "";
           txtQTYEmptyOC.Text = "";
           txtUnitCostEmptyOC.Text = "";
           ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOC2, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
           MyAuditProvider.Insert(this.GetType().ToString(), ViewState["MarginAnalysisID"].ToString(), MessageCenter.Mode.ADD, MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOC2, Page.Request, User);
           divOtherCost.Visible = false;
           grd_othercost.Visible = true;
           btnaddothercost.Visible = true;
       }
       else
       {
           //Displays a Message on the Validation Summary (Service Id does not exist)
           ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.SaveServiceDetailOC, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
       }
   }
   catch
   {
       //Displays a Message on the Validation Summary (Error on Saving)
       ValidationMessage.ShowValidationMessage(MessageCenter.CashExpenseMaintenace.InsertOCError, "SaveEmptyOC", this.Page);
   }

   finally
   {
       //Rebinds the Grid
       populategrd_othercost();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in `checkservicedetailid()`?

Comment: also in stead of `if(checkservicedetailid() != null)` try `var obj=checkservicedetailid(); if(obj!=null)` and later replace of `tblCashExpenses.ServiceDetailsID = checkservicedetailid().ServiceDetailsID;` with `tblCashExpenses.ServiceDetailsID = obj.ServiceDetailsID;`

Comment: Post CashExpense class properties here.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Hi, i already added the checkservicedetailid above.. thanks

Comment: @AVD CashExpense is a Data.Entity.

Comment: I've posted an idea, but could you post the method signature of `ServiceDetails_worker.get(...)` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell hi,, heres the code for that

 public IEnumerable<ServiceDetail> get(Expression<Func<ServiceDetail, Boolean>> express)
        {
            return ServiceDetailsDB.ServiceDetails.Where(express);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all of the solution given to me both by my peers as well as the solution provided here, from GC.Collect, to disposing linq datacontext after use etc. however the error keeps on occurring, i then tried to remove the update panel, Ive read a site that showed how ridiculous update panel when it comes to handling data esp when a function is done repeatedly. And poof! the memory problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from your code here:

```
ServiceDetail checkservicedetailid = ServiceDetails_worker.get(
    a => a.ServiceName == ServiceName &&
         a.MarginAnalysisID == checkmarginanalysisid().MarginAnalysisID
).SingleOrDefault();
```

that `.get()` is taking a `Func<SomeType, bool>`, and you are doing something like:

```
var row = dbCtx.SomeTable.Where(predicate);
```

(please correct me here if I'm incorrect)

This, however, is using LINQ-to-Objects, meaning: it is loading **every row** from the table to the client and testing locally. That'll hurt memory, especially if a different db-context is created for each row. Additionally, the `checkmarginanalysisid()` call is being executed per row, when presumably it doesn't change between rows.

You should be testing this with an `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>` which would be translated to TSQL and executed at the server. You may also need to remove untranslatable methods, i.e.

```
var marginAnalysisId = checkmarginanalysisid().MarginAnalysisID;
ServiceDetail checkservicedetailid = ServiceDetails_worker.get(
    a => a.ServiceName == ServiceName &&
         a.MarginAnalysisID == marginAnalysisId
).SingleOrDefault();
```

where that is `get(Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>)`.

Comment: hi, heres my get function 
  public IEnumerable<ServiceDetail> get(Expression<Func<ServiceDetail, Boolean>> express)
        {
            return ServiceDetailsDB.ServiceDetails.Where(express);
        }

Comment: so what can i do to fix this?

Comment: @anonymous1110 if it is, as you suggest, an expression... then - can you do a SQL trace (or similar) and check what data is going over the wire? what the query is etc? mainly to check: where is it filtering?